# Is it possible "extend" ThemeData in Flutter

Tags: dart, flutter

I might very well be missing something as I'm so new to flutter, but I'm finding ThemeData's options very limited (at least with my understanding of how to implement it).

If you look at this random design below from MaterialUp, I'd want to model something *roughly* like:

`Themedata.cyclingColor = Color.pink;
ThemeData.runningColor = Color.green;`

That way everywhere in my app I can reference cycling, running, swimming, gym colors (Or whatever colors make sense in the context of my app/design) and keep things consistent.

[image: Random design from MaterialUp]

Is there a recommended way to achieve this currently in Flutter? What are my options?

Comment: Do these colors ever change? You could make them just const values. You can also make a different InheritedWidget with your custom theme data. The default ThemeData is mainly for all (material) widgets of the framework.

Comment: See https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/16487#event-1573761656

Answer (score 29):

I recommend this approach, which is simple, works with hot reload and can be easily extended to support switching between dark and light themes.

First create your own analog to `ThemeData`, let's call it `AppThemeData`:

```
class AppThemeData {
  final BorderRadius borderRadius = BorderRadius.circular(8);

  final Color colorYellow = Color(0xffffff00);
  final Color colorPrimary = Color(0xffabcdef);

  ThemeData get materialTheme {
    return ThemeData(
        primaryColor: colorPrimary
    );
  }
}
```

The `materialTheme` can be used whenever the standard `ThemeData` is needed.

Then create a widget called `AppTheme`, which provides an instance of `AppThemeData` using the `provider` package.

```
class AppTheme extends StatelessWidget {
  final Widget child;

  AppTheme({this.child});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final themeData = AppThemeData(context);
    return Provider.value(value: themeData, child: child);
  }
}
```

Finally, wrap the whole app with `AppTheme`. To access the theme you can call `context.watch<AppThemeData>()`. Or create this extension...

```
extension BuildContextExtension on BuildContext {
  AppThemeData get appTheme {
    return watch<AppThemeData>();
  }
}
```

... and use `context.appTheme`. I usually put `final theme = context.appTheme;` on the first line of the widget build method.

Comment: That is slick, I love the usage of provider. Totally fixed my issue!

Comment: Wait, you will generate new instance of `ThemeData` each time you call `materialTheme`.

Comment: @AlexSemeniuk Yes, but in practice it's only called once.

Comment: @fhucho By the way, you haven't specified where and how exactly it will be used.

Comment: Been working on this for a bit now and unable to get it to work. I find two issues. 1 In AppTheme class you try to return context to AppThemeData although it is not setup to receive it. 2 I get an error telling me that "watch" is not defined for BuildContext. Am I missing something?

Comment: SOLVED – I had to update my version of provider.

Comment: @DanielDodd, How did you resolve the context issue?

Comment: Works with me! Thanks!

Comment: Yeah I haven't ran it and a Flutter beginner but I don't understand how `AppThemeData(context)` works given there is no constructor defined that accepts `context`?

Answer (score 28):

**Updated for null-safety**

I've extended standard `ThemeData` class so that at any time one could access own theme fields like that:

```
Theme.of(context).own().errorShade
```

Or like that:

```
ownTheme(context).errorShade
```

A theme can be defined and extended with new fields as follows(via `addOwn()` called on a certain `ThemeData` instance):

```
final ThemeData lightTheme = ThemeData.light().copyWith(
    accentColor: Colors.grey.withAlpha(128),
    backgroundColor: Color.fromARGB(255, 255, 255, 255),
    textTheme: TextTheme(
      caption: TextStyle(
          fontSize: 17.0, fontFamily: 'Montserrat', color: Colors.black),
    ))
  ..addOwn(OwnThemeFields(
      errorShade: Color.fromARGB(240, 255, 200, 200),
      textBaloon: Color.fromARGB(240, 255, 200, 200)));

final ThemeData darkTheme = ThemeData.dark().copyWith( ...
...
```

Themes can be applied to `MaterialApp` widget in a conventional way:

```
MaterialApp(
...
  theme: lightTheme,
  darkTheme: darkTheme,
)
```

The idea is to put all custom fields required for theming in a separate class `OwnThemeFields`.

Then extend `ThemeData` class with 2 methods:

1. `addOwn()` that connects a certain instance of `ThemedData` to `OwnThemeFields` instance
2. `own()` that allows to lookup for own fields associated with the given theme data

Also `ownTheme` helper method can be created to shorten the extraction of own fields.

```
class OwnThemeFields {
  final Color? errorShade;
  final Color? textBaloon;

  const OwnThemeFields({Color? errorShade, Color? textBaloon})
      : this.errorShade = errorShade,
        this.textBaloon = textBaloon;

  factory OwnThemeFields.empty() {
    return OwnThemeFields(errorShade: Colors.black, textBaloon: Colors.black);
  }
}
    
extension ThemeDataExtensions on ThemeData {
  static Map<InputDecorationTheme, OwnThemeFields> _own = {};

  void addOwn(OwnThemeFields own) {
    _own[this.inputDecorationTheme] = own;
  }

  static OwnThemeFields? empty = null;

  OwnThemeFields own() {
    var o = _own[this.inputDecorationTheme];
    if (o == null) {
      if (empty == null) empty = OwnThemeFields.empty();
      o = empty;
    }
    return o!;
  }
}

OwnThemeFields ownTheme(BuildContext context) => Theme.of(context).own();
```

Complete source: https://github.com/maxim-saplin/dikt/blob/master/lib/ui/themes.dart

Comment: Great solution!

Comment: It does not change the colors upon switching themes in app unless you hot reload

Comment: @Maxim I love your solution but the only problem is lets say I have 2 different themedata variables and each have their own '..addOwn' function. When I change the theme in the app, the OwnThemeFields does not change but stays to a fixed color. Do you know a workaround please? Would be easier for me to explain through share screen

Comment: Since ThemedData is immutable, you can't change anything in a given instance. I assume that you clone it with copyWith() and lose Own Fields that were previously set. Since the fields are tightly coupled with certain instance of ThemedData you can try calling the ownFields() right after copyWith() to bind the fields to a new instance of TD.

Comment: Smart solution. But need to be modified for Null safety

Comment: Modified for null-safety. Thanks for pointing out.

Comment: @MaximSaplin Any idea why the theme doesn't change upon system theme switch?
It seems it always uses the last theme on MaterialApp (if darktheme is under theme it'll always use dark).

Comment: Do you mean that switching system theme doesn't apply own fields while the rest of the theme works fine?

Comment: @MaximSaplin You rely on `inputDecorationTheme` to key the collection and nothing ensures that this won't be a constant one. I would suggest to rely on `brightness` instead (with a caveat comment in the code for the case if the brightness happens to be that same for both themes, the programmer should select something else).

Comment: But yes, the original problam remains: it won't be picked up on in-app theme change, only on next start.

Answer (score 15):

2022: Use ThemeExtensions introduced in flutter 3

Here's [a link](https://medium.com/@laksh.parnami/flutter-3-themedata-finally-extendeddd-aa0069cc9996)! to the medium article I wrote.

1. Create your ThemeExtension class

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

@immutable
class MyCardTheme extends ThemeExtension<MyCardTheme> {
  const MyCardTheme({
    this.background = Colors.white,
    this.shape = const RoundedRectangleBorder(
      borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(
        Radius.circular(8),
      ),
    ),
  });

  final Color background;
  final ShapeBorder shape;

  @override
  MyCardTheme copyWith({
    Color? background,
    ShapeBorder? shape,
  }) {
    return MyCardTheme(
      background: background ?? this.background,
      shape: shape ?? this.shape,
    );
  }

  @override
  MyCardTheme lerp(ThemeExtension<MyCardTheme>? other, double t) {
    if (other is! MyCardTheme) {
      return this;
    }
    return MyCardTheme(
      background: Color.lerp(background, other.background, t) ?? Colors.white,
      shape: ShapeBorder.lerp(shape, other.shape, t) ??
          const RoundedRectangleBorder(
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(
              Radius.circular(8),
            ),
          ),
    );
  }

  @override
  String toString() => 'MyCardTheme('
      'background: $background, radius: $shape'
      ')';
}
```

2. Create dark and light themes as per requirements

```
MyCardTheme lightCardTheme = MyCardTheme(
  background: Colors.blueGrey[200]!,
  shape: const RoundedRectangleBorder(
    borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(
      Radius.circular(24),
    ),
  ),
);

MyCardTheme darkCardTheme = MyCardTheme(
  background: Colors.blueGrey[800]!,
  shape: const RoundedRectangleBorder(
    borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(
      Radius.circular(24),
    ),
  ),
);
```

3. Add extensions to your ThemeData for both, light and dark themes.

```
 theme: ThemeData(
    primarySwatch: Colors.green,
    cardTheme: const CardTheme(
      shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(
          Radius.circular(8),
        ),
      ),
      color: Colors.green,
    ),
    extensions: <ThemeExtension<dynamic>>[
      lightCardTheme,
    ],
  ),
  darkTheme: ThemeData(
    brightness: Brightness.dark,
    primarySwatch: Colors.green,
    cardTheme: const CardTheme(
      shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(
          Radius.circular(8),
        ),
      ),
      color: Colors.green,
    ),
    extensions: <ThemeExtension<dynamic>>[
      darkCardTheme,
    ],
  ),
```

4. Use them in your build methods

```
final MyCardTheme customCardTheme =
        Theme.of(context).extension<MyCardTheme>()!;
Card(
    shape: customCardTheme.shape,
    color: customCardTheme.background,
    child: Container(
             padding: const EdgeInsets.all(16),
             child: const Text('Card styled from custom theme')),
          ),
    ),
```

Comment: Thanks, this is great! Using ThemeExtensions is much cleaner than some of the hackier methods of doing it!

Answer (score 9):

Instead of extending, you can use the new feature [ThemeExtension](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/ThemeExtension-class.html) in flutter.
We can add custom styling and even use class type theme configuration in css.

example:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/scheduler.dart';

@immutable
class MyColors extends ThemeExtension<MyColors> {
  const MyColors({
    required this.brandColor,
    required this.danger,
  });

  final Color? brandColor;
  final Color? danger;

  @override
  MyColors copyWith({Color? brandColor, Color? danger}) {
    return MyColors(
      brandColor: brandColor ?? this.brandColor,
      danger: danger ?? this.danger,
    );
  }

  @override
  MyColors lerp(ThemeExtension<MyColors>? other, double t) {
    if (other is! MyColors) {
      return this;
    }
    return MyColors(
      brandColor: Color.lerp(brandColor, other.brandColor, t),
      danger: Color.lerp(danger, other.danger, t),
    );
  }

  // Optional
  @override
  String toString() => 'MyColors(brandColor: $brandColor, danger: $danger)';
}

void main() {
  // Slow down time to see lerping.
  timeDilation = 5.0;
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  static const String _title = 'Flutter Code Sample';

  @override
  State<MyApp> createState() => _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  bool isLightTheme = true;

  void toggleTheme() {
    setState(() => isLightTheme = !isLightTheme);
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: MyApp._title,
      theme: ThemeData.light().copyWith(
        extensions: <ThemeExtension<dynamic>>[
          const MyColors(
            brandColor: Color(0xFF1E88E5),
            danger: Color(0xFFE53935),
          ),
        ],
      ),
      darkTheme: ThemeData.dark().copyWith(
        extensions: <ThemeExtension<dynamic>>[
          const MyColors(
            brandColor: Color(0xFF90CAF9),
            danger: Color(0xFFEF9A9A),
          ),
        ],
      ),
      themeMode: isLightTheme ? ThemeMode.light : ThemeMode.dark,
      home: Home(
        isLightTheme: isLightTheme,
        toggleTheme: toggleTheme,
      ),
    );
  }
}

class Home extends StatelessWidget {
  const Home({
    Key? key,
    required this.isLightTheme,
    required this.toggleTheme,
  }) : super(key: key);

  final bool isLightTheme;
  final void Function() toggleTheme;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final MyColors myColors = Theme.of(context).extension<MyColors>()!;
    return Material(
      child: Center(
          child: Row(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
        children: <Widget>[
          Container(width: 100, height: 100, color: myColors.brandColor),
          const SizedBox(width: 10),
          Container(width: 100, height: 100, color: myColors.danger),
          const SizedBox(width: 50),
          IconButton(
            icon: Icon(isLightTheme ? Icons.nightlight : Icons.wb_sunny),
            onPressed: toggleTheme,
          ),
        ],
      )),
    );
  }
}
```

from [Flutter API Documentation](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/ThemeExtension-class.html)

Answer (score 7):

You can't extend `ThemeData` because then material components won't find it anymore.

You can just create and provide `MyThemeData` in addition to the `ThemeData` included in Flutter the same way.

Create a widget `CustomThemeWidget` that extends `InheritedWidget` and provide your custom theme there.

When you want to get a value from the current theme use

```
myTheme = CustomThemeWidget.of(context).myTheme;
```

To change the current theme change the `MyThemeData` in `CustomThemeWidget.myTheme`

**Update**

Like shown in https://github.com/flutter/flutter/pull/14793/files, it should be possible to extend `ThemeData` and provide it as `ThemeData` by overriding `runtimeType`

See also the comment in https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/16487#event-1573761656

Comment: Interesting idea. How would we get a custom type into that map with another type as key?

Comment: I think I get it now. You want to make a custom `InheritedWidget` that supports that use case. Sounds like a great idea.

Comment: Sounds promising :)

Comment: Sorry, I have to prepare for a meeting

Comment: Can you explain updates. From the comment https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/16487#event-1573761656 this is what I'm looking for. But don't understand how you updates helps?

Comment: Bad luck the solution you updated https://github.com/flutter/flutter/pull/14793/files, Never been merged.

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer I just look into the code and curious.
Why we can't extends ThemeData?
ThemeData isn't InheritedWidget, Theme is.

Answer (score 5):

I have also found that the `ThemeData` is restricting. What I have done, and will be doing for all of my apps in the future is creating my own `ThemeData`.

I have created a file named `color_themes.dart` and created a `class` named `ColorThemes` with constructors with the name of the colors that I desire. such as `cyclingColor`;

```
class ColorThemes {
    static const cyclingColor = const Color(0xffb74093); 
}
```

You can then call these colors by importing the file and calling `ColorThemes.cyclingColor` You can assign these values within your `ThemeData` to have these colors default to your `ColorThemes`. One of the benefits with using this method is that you do not need to use/reference `context` like so `ThemeData.of(context)` making it a lot easier to use your code in extracted widgets.

Comment: how about switching themes in the app in runtime?

Comment: Then, you avoid the benefits of multiple theming, the dark mode as well.

Answer (score 5):

#### Dart 2.7 later, extension support

you can add extension for system class

only add instance property is easy, but if you would get a dynamic color

you need think about it. for example, Use a constant to get the colors in light and dark modes

Determine if it is dark mode

**two ways**

- `MediaQuery.of(context).platformBrightnes  == Brightness.dark;`
- `Theme.of(context).brightness == Brightness.dark;`

`As you can see, you need the context, the context`

**Add Extension for BuildContext**

Here is the code

```
extension MYContext on BuildContext {
  Color dynamicColor({int light, int dark}) {
    return (Theme.of(this).brightness == Brightness.light)
        ? Color(light)
        : Color(dark);
  }

  Color dynamicColour({Color light, Color dark}) {
    return (Theme.of(this).brightness == Brightness.light)
        ? light
        : dark;
  }

  /// the white background
  Color get bgWhite => dynamicColor(light: 0xFFFFFFFF, dark: 0xFF000000);
}
```

**How to use**

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'buildcontext_extension.dart';

class Test extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      color: context.bgWhite,
    );
  }
}
```

Also

This color may require multiple files, so you can create a public.dart file to manage it all

`Like This`

public.dart

```
library public;

// Export some common header files

// extensions
export 'buildcontext_extension.dart';
```

**DarkMode images support**

Put the light images in the same category as the dark ones

`some code`

```dart
static String getImgPath(String name, {
    String folder = '', 
    String format = 'png', 
    bool isDark = false, 
    bool needDark = true
  }) {
    String finalImagePath;
    if (needDark) {
      final folderName = isDark ? '${folder}_dark' : folder;
      finalImagePath = 'assets/images/$folderName/$name.$format';
    } else {
      finalImagePath = 'assets/images/$folder/$name.$format';
    }
    String isDarkPath = isDark ? " DarkMode" : " LightMode";
    print('$isDarkPath imagePath  $finalImagePath');
    return finalImagePath;
  }
```

Comment: I'd like your approach.

Comment: It's absolutely ugly way. Context object is not some sort of "app context" (like the one might think), it's a pointer to current element in an element tree. It shouldn't have any unrelated data.

Answer (score 4):

I solved this problem also for multiple themes by creating a `CustomThemeData` class like this:

```
class CustomThemeData {
    final double imageSize;

    CustomThemeData({
        this.imageSize = 100,
    });
}
```

Then, creating instances for each Theme:

```
final _customTheme = CustomThemeData(imageSize: 150);
final _customDarkTheme = CustomThemeData();
```

And writing an extension on `ThemeData`:

```
extension CustomTheme on ThemeData {
    CustomThemeData get custom => brightness == Brightness.dark ? _customDarkTheme : _customTheme;
}
```

Finally, the value can be accessed like this:

```
Theme.of(context).custom.imageSize
```

For more information see: https://bettercoding.dev/flutter/tutorial-themes-riverpod/#custom_attributes_extending_themedata

Comment: Thanks for this. Just clarifying, would this allow for multiple different themes that the user can select between manually, eg. a red theme, blue theme, dark theme, black theme? Or does it just allow for light and dark themes?

Comment: Unfortunately, Flutter only supports dark and light themes out of the box (by using `theme` and `darkTheme`of `MaterialApp`). You could set the `theme` dynamically (e.g. using a `StateNotifierProvider`), but then the solution would be far more complicated.

Comment: this was exactly the solution I was looking for, thank you

Answer (score 3):

use this lib [adaptive_theme](https://pub.dev/packages/adaptive_theme) for theme switch.
And create extension of ColorSheme

```
extension MenuColorScheme on ColorScheme {
      Color get menuBackground => brightness == Brightness.light
          ? InlLightColors.White
          : InlDarkColors.Black;
}
```

In widget use that

```
Container(
      color: Theme.of(context).colorScheme.menuBackground,
...
)
```

This way is very simple and elegance. Nice to codding.

Answer (score 1):

A simple workaround if you are not using all the textTheme headlines you can set some colors of some of them and use them like you normally use other colors.

set the headline1 color:
`ThemeData(textTheme: TextTheme(headline1: TextStyle(color: Colors.red),),),`

Use it:
`RawMaterialButton(fillColor: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headline1.color,onPressed: onPressed,)`

Answer (score 0):

I created an implementation analog to the implementation of `ThemeData`:

```
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
     final Brightness platformBrightness = Theme.of(context).brightness;
     final bool darkTheme = platformBrightness == Brightness.dark;

     return CustomAppTheme(
               customAppTheme:
                   darkTheme ? CustomAppThemeData.dark : CustomAppThemeData.light,
               child: Icon(Icons.add, color: CustomAppTheme.of(context).addColor,),
     );
}
```

```
import 'package:calendarflutter/style/custom_app_theme_data.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class CustomAppTheme extends InheritedWidget {
  CustomAppTheme({
    Key key,
    @required Widget child,
    this.customAppTheme,
  }) : super(key: key, child: child);

  final CustomAppThemeData customAppTheme;

  static CustomAppThemeData of(BuildContext context) {
    return context
        .dependOnInheritedWidgetOfExactType<CustomAppTheme>()
        .customAppTheme;
  }

  @override
  bool updateShouldNotify(CustomAppTheme oldWidget) =>
      customAppTheme != oldWidget.customAppTheme;
}
```

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class CustomAppThemeData {
  final Color plusColor;

  const CustomAppThemeData({
    @required this.plusColor,
  });

  static CustomAppThemeData get dark {
    return CustomAppThemeData(
      plusColor: Colors.red,
    );
  }

  static CustomAppThemeData get light {
    return CustomAppThemeData(
      plusColor: Colors.green,
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: I go into a little more detail in my blog post: www.felixlarsen.com/blog/custom-themedata-flutter-extension

Answer (score 0):

To extend (pun not intended) the answer of Maxim Saplin:

You may encounter a problem, where theme stays on the last one initialized in your code. This is happening because InputDecorationTheme is always the same for all of yours themes.

What solved it for me, was changing key (InputDecorationTheme) in _own to something unique, like themeID (you'll have to implement it somehow).