# Flutter Custom Colors Tree

Tags: flutter, object, colors, tree

New to Flutter and am trying to incorporate a tree that I have used for colors on a website as usable colors within Flutter. I have managed so far to create custom colors but only by declaring them individually.

```
class AppColors {
  final boo = const Color.fromRGBO(0, 32, 255, 1);

  const AppColors();
}

class AppTheme {
  static const colors = AppColors();
}
```

This I use in app via `AppTheme.colors.boo`

What I want to be able to do is use my entire color scheme as a tree whereby I can grab whatever color I want from the scheme. Here is a basic repository in JSON (I'm not looking to convert from json merely understand how to do this in Flutter (very new, but understand JS well)).

```
{
    "background": {
        "solid": {
            "light": "255, 255 ,255, 1",
            "dark": "0, 0 ,0, 1"
        },
        "light": {
            "primary": "255, 255, 255, 0.84",
            "secondary": "240, 240, 248, 0.84",
            "tertiary": "224, 224, 232, 0.84"
        },
        "dark": {
            "primary": "0, 0, 0, 0.84",
            "secondary": "32, 32, 40, 0.84",
            "tertiary": "64, 64, 72, 0.84"
        }
    },
```

...

Then to be able to use them in my app as `AppTheme.colors.background.solid` for example.

I appreciate these are rather fundamental issues I am having but this is my way of learning.

One way I have found is this:

```
class AppColors {
  final backgroundSolid = const Color.fromRGBO(255, 255, 255, 1);
  final backgroundPrimary = const Color.fromRGBO(255, 255, 255, 0.84);
  final backgroundSecondary = const Color.fromRGBO(240, 240, 248, 0.84);
  final backgroundTertiary = const Color.fromRGBO(224, 224, 232, 0.84);

  const AppColors();
}

class AppTheme {
  static const colors = AppColors();
}
```

Is this a reasonable approach?

Comment: You can look at (flutter theme doc)[https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/design/themes] to see how can you set colors to all the application, and use them with Theme.of(context).

Comment: Furthermore, you can look at Material Design Patterns to see how Flutter uses colors and other theme configs through the app

Comment: Thanks. I've taken a look but I'm effectively trying to give custom keys for my colors which, from what I can see, doesn't seem to be possible via this means.

Comment: @GuilhermeGabanelli Would this be a bad way of doing it:
extension AppColors on CupertinoThemeData {
  Color get BackgroundSolid {
    return Color.fromRGBO(255, 255, 255, 1);
  }
....

Comment: Or rather:  (updating question)

Comment: You can use [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49172746/is-it-possible-extend-themedata-in-flutter) to do that. Using provider to access the theme in any widget on the tree. In that way you can set any name to the theme variables.